# Inject content into an injected div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to inject the time into an input field that has just been injected? To clarify I am using CMB2 which is a WordPress library to create Custom Meta Boxes. I am using the `repeating field` field and this injects a `div` with a few fields. I want to use a button to add the current time to an input field.

I can do this if the post has been saved and the div is already in the DOM, but I cannot add the time to a newly created row/div.

Is it possible to add the time to a field that has been injected? If so, how? Any help would be appreciated.

I apologize if this does not make any sense. Its 1:40am and I cannot find the words to explain is too well.

This is how I get the time and add it to the input field.

```
(function($) {

var strDateTime = // bunch of code to get date...

$('.getTime').on('click', function(e) {
    var $root = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    $root.parent().find('.note_timestamp').val(strDateTime);

});

}(jQuery));
```

This works fine if the div block has been saved and not newly injected, but if I click the add row button and the div is injected into the dom the `getTime` onclick event does not fire.

Comment: Paste some code in your question which will explain your efforts done so far. Theoretically it is near to impossible to find what is wrong with implementation.

Comment: I just updated my question with the bit of code that I have working.

Comment: use `$(document).on('click','.getTime',function(e){ // your code});`

Comment: @HarshMakani Thank you! Any explanation on why it needs to be done this way? I'm just trying to soak up some JavaScript knowledge. Thanks again.

Comment: what $('.getTime') will do is search in existing DOM in which your newly created elements won't be present where as what $(document) does is researches in in whole document again.

Comment: ahhhh. Makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that handler gets added only once when the page first loads. You'd have to attach it to something that is on the page, and then filter it like so:

```
$('body').on('click', '.getTime', function(e) {
    var $root = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    $root.parent().find('.note_timestamp').val(strDateTime);
});
```